# Libgdx how execute code after an action?

Tags: java, libgdx

How is possible to execute Java code after actor's action?

It's very important for me to execute this Java code once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is [`RunnableAction`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/RunnableAction.html) for that, to which you supply a `Runnable`. You can queue it via a `SequenceAction`.

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.*;

Actor actor = new Image();
actor.addAction(moveTo(10, 20, 0.5f));
RunnableAction run = new RunnableAction();
run.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("LEEEROOOOOY JEEEEEEENKINS");
    }
});
actor.addAction(sequence(moveTo(200, 100, 2), run));
```

Comment: what's wrong with `Runnable r = new Runnable(){ ...override...}`and then `actor.addAction(sequence(...whatever..., Actions.run(r)))`?

Comment: @fr_andres Absolutely nothing. It's exactly the same, only a little bit shorter.

Comment: great! thanks. I find also the `run(r)` version more readable, but that's probably because I''m more used to it

Comment: There is a demo/code sample on how to use RunnableAction here: https://libgdx.info/runnable-action/  You can execute the code with a SequenceAction to execute it after another action.

Comment: If you want to set different Runnables to the same RunnableAction, don't forget to call runnableAction.reset(), or else only the first Runnable will be executed.